# Proving that if $\sum_{k = m}^{\infty}P(A_k) < \infty$ then $\lim_{m \rightarrow \infty}\sum_{k = m}^{\infty}P(A_k) = 0$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, self-learning

I want to prove that if $\sum_{k = m}^{\infty}P(A_k) < \infty$ then $\lim_{m \rightarrow \infty}\sum_{k = m}^\infty P(A_k) = 0$.

Bu I am not quite there, I will write where I got to trying to do this.

So  $\sum_{k = m}^\infty P(A_k)$ converges because the sequence of partial sums is increasing and bounded.

Denote the sequence of partial sums as $b_a =  P(A_1)+ P(A_2)+ \cdots + P(A_a) $

This means that for every $\epsilon >0$ there exists a $p \in N$ s.t. whenever $a \ge p$ then  $|b_a - L| < \epsilon \implies -\epsilon < b_a - L < \epsilon \implies -\epsilon - b_a < - L \implies L < \epsilon + b_a $.

Now we know that $P(A_m)+ P(A_{m+1})+ \cdots \le L < \epsilon + b_a $ so, focusing now on the $\lim_{m \rightarrow \infty}$, if we choose $m = p$ we get that for every $\epsilon > 0$:

$$\left|\sum_{k = m}^\infty P(A_k) \right| \cdots$$

It seems pretty straightforward but I can't seem to pick the right $m$ to do the job.

Comment: convergent series, convergent sequence, cauchy sequence, and the conclusion.

Comment: $P$ is probability measure, ie $P(A_k) \geq 0, \forall k$? I feel like you're already there. I think it's ok in this case to just say "if $L = \limsup \sum_{k=1}^\infty P(A_k)$ then for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exist a $p$ where  for all $m > p$, $\sum_{k=m}^\infty P(A_k) < \epsilon$, without explicitly stating how to compute $L$ or $p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S_n = \Sigma_{k=1}^n P(A_k) $ and as $\Sigma_{k=m}^{\infty} P(A_k) <\infty$, we can deduce that $S_n$ converges and lets say it converges to $S < \infty$. Now, observe that $\Sigma_{k=m}^{\infty} P(A_k) = S-S_m$ and let $m \to \infty $ on both sides. So, we have

$$\lim_{m \to \infty}\Sigma_{k=m}^{\infty} P(A_k) = \lim_{m \to \infty}(S-S_m) = 0$$

Answer (score 1):

I think this is true for *any* convergent series:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\;\;\;\text{converges}\;\;\iff\;\text{its partial sums sequence is Cauchy}\;\iff$$

$$\forall\;\epsilon>0\;\exists\; N\in\Bbb N\;\;s.t.\;\;m>N\;,\;p>0\implies |s_{m+p}-s_m|<\epsilon\iff$$

$$\left|\sum_{n=1}^{m+p} a_n-\sum_{n=1}^m a_n\right|=\left|\sum_{n=m+1}^{m+p}a_n\right|<\epsilon$$

**Added:** As written in my comment below, one can directly show the claim in the question without using Cauchy's Condition for series.

First, the series is positive as $\;P(A_k)\ge 0\;\;\forall\,k\;$ , so that the series converges iff it is bounded. Suppose

$$\begin{cases}\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n=A\\{}\\s_m:=\sum\limits_{n=1}^m a_n\end{cases}\;\;\;\implies \sum_{n=m+1}^\infty a_n= A-s_m\xrightarrow[m\to\infty]{}A-A=0$$

since $\;\{s_m\}\;$is the sequence of partial sums of the series.

Comment: Right but his prompt only says that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n < \infty$, not that it converges. For that we need the assumption $a_n \geq 0$. Otherwise $1,-1,1,-1,...$ is a counterexample.

Comment: @whyyes Indeed so, yet the question's tagged "Probability theory" , so I assumed the notation $\;P(A_k)\;$ means "probability of event $\;A_k\;$" , and this means the series is positive.

Comment: Oh yeah I see what your proof is doing. I just think it's a nontrivial step to say that series is bounded + elements are nonnegative $\Rightarrow$ series converges. But otherwise I agree with your proof. Though, slightly unrelated, but I see this technique you're using all the time, showing that finite partial sums are Cauchy rather than just showing the tail is Cauchy ($\sum_{n=m}^p a_n$ Cauchy rather than $\sum_{n=m}^\infty a_n$ Cauchy). Is there a reason for that? I see it in proofs all the time, so I'm just curious, since I'm not a math major and I intuitively find the notation cumbersome.

Comment: @whyyes I think that step is trivial for anyone knowing the basics of infinite series, since if the series is positive its partial sums sequence is monotonic increasing and thus it converges (i.e., the series converges) iff its bounded. About the tail going to zero: it follows almost at once from convergence: $$\sum_{n=m+1}^\infty a_n=A-s_m\xrightarrow[m\to\infty]{}A-A=0$$ with $\;A\;$ the sum of the infinite series, and you're right: Cauchy's Condition is something we can do without here. Thanks.

Comment: Why is this proof down-voted? Is there an error? It convinced me and I think this is what @Chou was Implying.

Comment: @Monolite Don't worry about the downvote:I've these days a downvoter stalker and the system can't, or won't, do anything about it. It's no problem at all. Yet if you found the answer helpful you could upvote it now.